# Detect clicks in an iframe (same domain) when it is loaded in a popup

Tags: html, jquery, iframe, local-storage

I am having trouble detecting clicks in my iframe (same domain) that is loaded in a popup. I need to indicate in local storage when the button has been clicked. Not sure what I am doing wrong - any help would be appreciated! Also a thing to note, even though the iframe page is on the same domain, I will not have any access to it to edit or add any codes. Below is my code for reference.

HTML:

```
<div class="popup-form">
    <div class="box-form">
        <span class="close-form" id="close-form">x close</span>
        <div id="box-iframe"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-form">click me</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.btn-form').click(function(){ 
      
      $(".popup-form").fadeIn(function(){

        var url = 'example.html',
        iFrameElem = $('#box-iframe')
            .append('<iframe class="dl-frame" src="' + url + '" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>')
            .find('.dl-frame').get(0),
        iDoc = iFrameElem.contentDocument || iFrameElem.contentWindow.document;

        $(iDoc).ready(function (event) {
            alert('iframe ready!');

            $(".dl-frame").contents().find('#btn-link').on("mousedown, mouseup, click", function(){
                alert("Button click detected inside iframe.");
                localStorage.setItem('buttonClicked', 1);
            });
        });
      });
```

Comment: @charlietfl no, the jquery code is currently loaded in the parent page. i will need to change the iframe url upon deployment so technically i do not have access to add or edit any codes in the page within the iframe.